# SWRevealViewController shows 10 seconds delay on initial view controller

Tags: swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewController` for an app. Before the main storyboard, I have another storyboard where I am logging in the user and setting him up for use.  Once the user is logged in, I present the reveal view controller, which has the proper segues to show my dashboard view controller.

`SWRevealViewController` works perfectly, except for one specific problem: On initial load to my dashboard view controller, there is a 10 second delay before my navigation button shows on the navigation bar.  If you wait for it and click the navigation button and go to another screen and then back to the dashboard view controller, the navigation would be there instantly.

What could cause this delay?  It is almost as if it needs a `dispatch_async` on `SWRevealViewController`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

From the description you gave, it seems to me that the display of the navigation buttons is not happening in the main thread. I would agree that dispatch_async might be needed here.  I do find it strange that this is happening since navigation itself happens in the main thread.

Comment: Since it is not my code that is doing the display of those items, any ideas where in SWRevealViewController I would put that code?